# Java code works in IDE but not with jar on different computer

Tags: java, jar, javax.imageio, platform

I am creating a java app in netbeans that will compress multi-page tiff images. Part of that process is to use the various jai, jai-imageIO, etc image libraries. In particular, I have a method that gets the bit depth of the image and it works fine in the IDE and on my local machine if I run it through the command line with the built .jar file. The method in question is as follows:

```
private synchronized void setBitDepth() {
       if(this.getImageInputStream() == null) {
           System.out.println("ImageInputStreamFailure");
       } try {
           //System.out.println("Path: " + this.testTiff);
           ImageInputStream testInStream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new File(this.testTiff)); //test
           Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(testInStream);
           ImageReader reader;
           if(!readers.hasNext()) {
               throw new IOException("Cant read format...");
           }  else {
               reader = readers.next();
           }
           reader.setInput(this.getImageInputStream(), true, true);
           this.bitDepth = reader.getImageTypes(0).next().getColorModel().getPixelSize();
           reader.dispose();
       } catch(IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } 
    }
```

If I package my project into a jar file and run it on a different machine that has java on it, this method always throws the `IOException("Cant read format...")` exception. I've tried multiple remedies including trying to package up all of my external libraries into the single jar file as well as cleaning and rebuilding my project multiple times, but I cannot seem to figure out why this isn't working across multiple platforms that all have java installed.

Comment: What JDK do you use on IDE and which one on the other machines? Most probably the JDK/JRE on the other machines is an older one and does not have the libraries for reading that image format.

Comment: I use the jre7 and jdk1.7.0_45 on the machine with the IDE. On the test machine that I am trying to run the jar on, I have jre6, jre7, and jdk1.7.0_05 installed. I take it I should probably install the latest JDK on the target machine?

Comment: Is the error appearing on all the test machines?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is related to [Java Advanced Imaging-Image](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/jai-142803.html) library, which is not part of SDK?
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/current-142188.html

Comment: Since the library comes bundled in its own installer package, how exactly would I include that install in my app with something like Inno Setup Compiler?

Comment: Your problem is related to JAI? Is JAI attached to your application bundle?